# Blank screen when displaying vector file from spreadsheet in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vrt, layer-file, create, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet plugin installed. The Excel spreadsheet has coordinates in Australia's national grid  GDA94 zone 56 which are metric. I open the Excel file and use the geometry button and limiting function.

The easting and northings x and y are set and the CRS is selected for this grid specifically. I've done the same for this file as a CSV, as well.

I just get a blank screen whether in a project or just this `.vrt`-file.
The pointer works in GDA 94 when I move it around the blank screen. I cannot activate the Layer Styling Apply button. It refuses to apply. All the tutorials work in latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: What version of qgis are you running? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Better still, can you share the spreadsheet, or maybe part of it, or if its confidential something like it that shows the same problem that you can share with some made-up numbers?